# Android mantain service connection through orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-service, android-service-binding

I'm developing an app which requires an `Activity` to bind to a `Service`. I'm using the usual `bindService` and `unbindService`. However, I'm trying to maintain the binding through orientation changes. For that, I'm overriding [`onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance()). But I'm facing to problems. To make the call to `unbind` I check if the `Activity`is finishing with `isFinishing()` and works fine but an `Exception` is being thrown warning a `ServiceConnection` has been leaked. I don't know if this can be worked around.

My main problem is, if after a rotation a call to `unbind` is made, I get an `IllegalArgumentException` with message *Service not registered*

I'm keeping and unbinding the original `ServiceConnection` but it is not working.

The binding is kept through orientation changes because `Fragment`s attached to the `Activity` are using the `Service` too.

Is there anyway to fix this? Or should I make a `ServiceConnection` in the `Fragment`s too?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting exception **ServiceConnection has been leaked** is because when you tried to bind the service with the ***serviceconnection*** object , you have used Activity context. So this will create a leak when your device orientation changes and you are saving the ServiceConnection .

To avoid the leak,during **binding** and **unbinding** the service anywhere in your Activity, use Application Context(`getApplicationContext()`) , this will fix your issue and you won't be leaking the ServiceConnection

binding:

```
getApplicationContext().bindService(new Intent(this, TestService.class), serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

unbinding:

```
getApplicationContext().unbindService(serviceConnection)
```